# google dialog flow how match entities with slightly different text?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying to add dialogflow into my current python script. It all works fine when I give the exact input dialog flow expects, but when a single letter is mistyped dialog flow won't give the correct output.

for example, I have an entity "redirect or redial" I can have synonym's for them like 'call again' or 'dial' but when I would type in 'dail' or 'all again' it will return the 'i did not understand you' message.

I do need this because the text I send to de dialog flow API will be directly from a speech to the voice application. I also know there is an option to feed audio input to the dialog flow API but I want to use another API to convert the text since I later want to add an extra step where I convert the text using google translate API.

I know its possible to just keep adding synonym's until you have matched them all but that doesn't seem right. I'm just wondering if there is a way to do this or just set the 'Allow automated expansion' on?

Comment: do you actually need entity for this? or should you add `call again`, or `dial` to your training phrases?

Comment: i want to return a value 'redirect' or 'dial' to my program, i think the only way to do this is to make an entity and set it as required?